# Windows light XML validator, works with non ".xml" files

Tags: windows, open-source, offline, xml

I often use Firefox to quickly spot what is the problem in a malformed XML file.
Unfortunately it only works if the filename extension is `.xml`.

What tool could I use instead?

Requirements:

- Very light and fast
- Minimalist GUI, command line acceptable too if fast to use
- Shows where XML is malformed (just XML is enough, but bonus for XML Schema)
- Open source
- Usable offline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) Obviously :)

It's by default really light since it's a pure editor.
But for XML support you will need a plugin like
 
[XML TOOLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/) and an [installation guide](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/NPP-XML-Tools-Plugin-Download-and-Install.html)

A screenshot of the plugin menu:[image]

The only "trap" with your requirements is that when checking XML syntax
a window pops-up showing where the first problem occured like this:
[image]

But I really can not remember a program which shows (like highlighted in red) where the xml is malformed generally.

Forgot to mention that the second image is when trying to validate a **non-XML file**, the plugin works generally with files opened with any extension

Answer (score 4):

You can use [XML Explorer](https://xmlexplorer.github.io/):

- free and open source
- Windows
- fast and lightweight
- validates XML documents using XSD Schema (specified in the document), shows a list of validation errors, and double-clicking an error navigates and selects the node.

[image]